# Scala Macros, generating type parameter calls

Tags: scala, generics, macros, scala-macros, squeryl

I'm trying to generalize setting up Squeryl (Slick poses the same problems AFAIK). I want to avoid having to name every case class explicitly for a number of general methods.

```
table[Person]
table[Bookmark]
etc.
```

This also goes for generating indexes, and creating wrapper methods around the CRUD methods for every case class.

So ideally what I want to do is have a list of classes and make them into tables, add indexes and add a wrapper method:

```
val listOfClasses = List(classOf[Person], classOf[Bookmark])
listOfClasses.foreach(clazz => {
  val tbl = table[clazz]
  tbl.id is indexed
  etc.
})
```

I thought Scala Macros would be the thing to apply here, since I don't think you can have values as type parameters. Also I need to generate methods for every type of the form:

```
def insert(model: Person): Person = persons.insert(model)
```

I've got my mits on an example on Macros but I don't know how to generate a generic datastructure.

I got this simple example to illustrate what I want:

```
def makeList_impl(c: Context)(clazz: c.Expr[Class[_]]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._

  reify {
    println(List[clazz.splice]()) // ERROR: error: type splice is not a member of c.Expr[Class[_]]
  }
}

def makeList(clazz: Class[_]): Unit = macro makeList_impl
```

How do I do this? Or is Scala Macros the wrong tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `reify` is not flexible enough for your use case, but there's good news. In macro paradise (and most likely in 2.11.0) we have a better tool to construct trees, called quasiquotes: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/quasiquotes.html.

```
scala> def makeList_impl(c: Context)(clazz: c.Expr[Class[_]]): c.Expr[Any] = {
     | import c.universe._
     | val ConstantType(Constant(tpe: Type)) = clazz.tree.tpe
     | c.Expr[Any](q"List[$tpe]()")
     | }
makeList_impl: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(clazz: c.Expr[Class[_]])c.Expr[Any]

scala> def makeList(clazz: Class[_]): Any = macro makeList_impl
defined term macro makeList: (clazz: Class[_])Any

scala> makeList(classOf[Int])
res2: List[Int] = List()

scala> makeList(classOf[String])
res3: List[String] = List()
```

Quasiquotes are even available in 2.10.x with a minor tweak to the build process (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html#macro_paradise_for_210x), so you might want to give them a try.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the reply. I did run across the `q".."` notation but couldn't find any documentation. That does exactly what I want it to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will probably not fill all your needs here, but it may help a bit:

The signature of `table` method looks like this:

```
protected def table[T]()(implicit manifestT: Manifest[T]): Table[T]
```

As you can see, it takes implicit `Manifest` object. That object is passed automatically by the compiler and contains information about type `T`. This is actually what Squeryl uses to inspect database entity type.

You can just pass these manifests explicitly like this:

```
val listOfManifests = List(manifest[Person], manifest[Bookmark])
listOfManifests.foreach(manifest => {
  val tbl = table()(manifest)
  tbl.id is indexed
  etc.
})
```

Unfortunately `tbl` in this code will have type similar to `Table[_ <: CommonSupertypeOfAllGivenEntities]` which means that all operations on it must be agnostic of concrete type of database entity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I'm using Squeryl 0.9.6-M1, this has an additional implicit argument:

`not enough arguments for method table: (implicit manifestT: scala.reflect.Manifest[T], implicit ked: org.squeryl.OptionalKeyedEntityDef[T, _])org.squeryl.Table[T]`

It would be an improvement although as you note yourself it's not ideal yet. I think Macros would give the answer there If I knew how to construct a type parametrized object based on a variable.